# Could not find or load main class error

Tags: java, cmd

I'm having trouble running my java application from the command line. This is what I am trying to run:

```
C:\Users\workspace\project>java -cp .\bin\calculator CalculatorController.class
```

All the class files are in the calculator folder and the main class is in the CalculatorController.class. Can anyone spot what im doing wrong?

Comment: Is calculator class in package if yes give the qualified name and run it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: Remove `.class` and give proper path

```
C:\Users\workspace\project>java -cp .\bin\calculator\CalculatorController
```

`.class` extension is not required while running java class.

Comment: Thanks for that. It now gives me a different error: C:\Users\workspace\project>java -cp .\bin\calculator CalculatorController
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Cal
(wrong name: calculator/CalculatorController)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)

Comment: @maloney you are welcome, for your new error, you can ask new question and please add source code to it, so it will be easy to identify the error.

Comment: Fixed by converting project to a jar and running that directly. I have a feeling the problem above was because I generated the classes using eclipse and I should have used the package location in front of the class name when running from the command line e.g. src.package.CalculatorController